# Form binding using Map<String,String> doesn't work

Tags: java, forms, playframework

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaForms

The page states that, with the given example data model,

```
public class User {
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

you can bind a Map to the form, and populate the data model, like this:

```
@Test
public void bindTest() {
    Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class);

    Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    anyData.put("email","bob@gmail.com");
    anyData.put("password", "password");

    User user = form.bind(anyData).get();

    assertEquals("bob@gmail.com", user.email);
    assertEquals("password", user.password);
}
```

This doesn't work. It fails on assertEquals. However, when I add setters and getters to the Users's public fields, it works. Like this:

```
public class User {
    public String email;
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String value) { email = value; }

    public String password;
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String value) { password = value; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this without adding getters and setters.

After all, the page tells me that "Note: The underlying binding is done using Spring data binder." Okay, so it probably has to do with the way Spring data binding works, but I'm pretty sure the public fields would do the job, without getters and setters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't Spring DataBinding require that the objects be valid java beans with setters?

Comment: Hmmm... that being the case, is the doc being inaccurate?

Comment: No... the doc says that it uses the Spring Data Binder. The Spring Data binder requires valid beans with getter/setter methods. The docs are accurate.

Comment: @Kylar - Sorry if I'm being dumb... but if it requires valid beans with getter/setter methods, then shouldn't the playframeworks doc present the User class example  WITH the getter/setter, instead of just public fields? (That's what I mean by doc being inaccurate)

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, you may be right. If you find that the example is inaccurate, try posting your question to the mailing list or forum for play framework, and get them to correct it.